# Most efficient way to synchronize local folders and server (django dev)

Tags: django, sublimetext2, remote-server

I am currently using winSCP to transfer files back and forth, and using PuTTY to run the server **./restart** for when I edit my app/project .py files. I was wondering if there is a faster and more efficient to upload/download from the server instead of drag/drop and server restart.

Are there any django-specific scripts that automate some of this? Maybe through the editor? I'm currently using Sublime.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already, you should consider putting your project under version control, e.g. by using Git. Aside from a host of other benefits (branching, reverting, etc.) it will also help you sync your files between your development machine and your server.

[Git homepage](http://git-scm.com/)

As far as django (or any python project for that matter) is concerned, you should check out Fabric, which let's you automate a lot of tasks involved with deploying your code, such as restarting the server etc.

[Fabric homepage](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/index.html)

Comment: Capistrano could also be used for the deployement automation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano - https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki

Comment: There are a lot of good example Fabric config files around the web for deploying Django e.g. [this one](https://raw.github.com/gist/382545/7d28e74ee85f3d2ca02352a59892a1b169b53290/fabfile.py) from [this blog series](http://www.robgolding.com/blog/2011/11/12/django-in-production-part-1---the-stack/)